# Can CUDAVolumetricRender be combined with other 3D graphics?

Tags: cudalink

I have volumetric data, which I can render using `CUDAVolumetricRender[]`. However, I cannot seem to find a way to combine it with other 3D graphics, such as adding a bounding box, axes, labels, etc.

How is `CUDAVolumetricRender[]` supposed to be customized? It returns a `DynamicModule`, which is pretty opaque.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible.  After looking at it, it seems it's only a plain 2D image that's being dynamically updated.  But if you have version 9, you can use Raster3D and Image3D which easily solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you face here is that `CUDAVolumetricRender[]` does the projection onto the image plane on its own. The function I pointed out at the end of my answer to your other [CUDA related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22654/187) calculates this projection from the 3D data set onto the 2D image you see.

The situation is far from hopeless because `Image3D` in version 9 uses the same technique to render a 3D data set. In contrast to the CUDA renderer this data type can be used in combination with other `Graphics3D` directives. Creating a bounding box or axes is done in no time

```
data = Table[
   If[z == 0 && (Mod[x, 8] == 0 || Mod[y, 8] == 0) || (Abs[x] < 8 && 
       Abs[y] < 8 && -16 < z < 0), 255, 0], {z, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 
    50}, {x, -50, 50}];
img = Image3D[data, "Byte"]

Show[{img, Graphics3D[{Sphere[{10, 10, 90}, 5]}]}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
```

[image]