# How to make a volume CUDA rendering isometric?

Tags: cudalink

I just realized that the output of `CUDAVolumetricRender[]` uses (quite marked) perspective, which I do not want (for scientific data representation, it can be very misleading). How do I turn it off? (i.e. make it use an isometric projection)

Comment: Do you really need CUDAVolumetricRender?  If you have version 9, you can use Image3D and related functions.  It would be a simpler solution.

Comment: The source code of CUDAVolumetricRender is the file "volumeRender_kernel.cu", written in Cuda C. By me, the file is in `$InstallationDirectory <> \
"\\SystemFiles\\Links\\CUDALink\\CSource\\volumeRender_kernel.cu"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe what you mean when you speak of *heavy perspective* is the difference between orthogonal and perspective projection.

```
t = TransformationMatrix[
   RescalingTransform[{{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}].RotationTransform[
     Pi/5, {1, 0, 0}].RotationTransform[-Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}]];
p = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
GraphicsRow[
 With[{lines = 
      Table[{i, j}, {i, -2, 2, .3}, {j, -2, 2, .3}] /. {x_, y_} :> {x,
          y, 0}},
    Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[lines], Line[Transpose[lines]], Cuboid[]},
      Boxed -> False, ViewMatrix -> #]
    ] & /@ {Automatic, {t, p}}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The difference is rather subtle but when you observe the images closer then you see that in the left (perspective) image the parallel lines of the grid will meet somewhere if they would be longer. In the right image (orthogonal) this is not the case. Furthermore, you see that in the perspective projection distant grid-squares are smaller than the ones in the front. In the right image, all squares which are of the same size.

Let's look at the behavior of `Image3D`

```
data = Table[
   If[z == 0 && (Mod[x, 8] == 0 || Mod[y, 8] == 0) || (Abs[x] < 8 && 
       Abs[y] < 8 && -16 < z < 0), 255, 0], {z, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 
    50}, {x, -50, 50}];
Image3D[data, "Byte"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I wouldn't call this *heavy perspective*. At most it looks similar to the projection of the normal `Graphics3D`. Let's see what happens in the cuda renderer

```
CUDAVolumetricRender[data, Height -> 400, Width -> 400]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This doesn't look so bad at all. Unfortunately, the control of the `CUDAVolumetricRender` is implemented differently so I could not get the same viewpoint as in the `Image3D` but you could play yourself.

Let's say you really want to change the perspective in the `CUDAVolumetricRender` then I'm pretty sure you have to code it yourself. To give you a starting point: I would strongly advise to investigate in the `iNewFrame` function at line 663 of `volumeRender_kernel.cu`. Looks like this is the function which calculates the final projection:

```c
static void iNewFrame() {
mint ii, jj;
mint pixel;

#define PI 3.14159265f
float theta, psi;
theta = -viewRotation.x*PI/180.0f;
psi   = -viewRotation.y*PI/180.0f;

invViewMatrix[0] = cos(psi);
invViewMatrix[4] = sin(theta)*sin(psi);
invViewMatrix[8] = -cos(theta)*sin(psi);

invViewMatrix[1] = 0.0f;
invViewMatrix[5] = cos(theta);
invViewMatrix[9] = sin(theta);

invViewMatrix[2] = sin(psi);
invViewMatrix[6] = -sin(theta)*cos(psi);
invViewMatrix[10]= cos(theta)*cos(psi);

invViewMatrix[3] = -invViewMatrix[0]*viewTranslation.x -  \
  invViewMatrix[1]*viewTranslation.y - invViewMatrix[2]*viewTranslation.z;
invViewMatrix[7] = -invViewMatrix[4]*viewTranslation.x -\
  invViewMatrix[5]*viewTranslation.y - invViewMatrix[6]*viewTranslation.z;
invViewMatrix[11] = -invViewMatrix[8]*viewTranslation.x -\
  invViewMatrix[9]*viewTranslation.y - invViewMatrix[10]*viewTranslation.z;
/* ... */
}
```