# Depth from Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

Consider this simple 3D rendering with some geometric primitives:

```
Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1}}, .42], Cuboid[], 
  Polygon[{{-2, -2, 0}, {2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {-2, 2, 0}}], 
  Sphere[{.3, -.6, .5}, .5]}, Boxed -> False]
```

How can I get the depth of each *pixel* of the rendering, i.e. the distance of the corresponding point to the camera?

**Edit:** The required depth image would be something like the OpenGL z-buffer. Vertices alone are not enough - I need the depth of every pixel in the rendered image.

Comment: I have two applications: One where there are half a million (full image) and one with around 1000 (test points).

Comment: Pixels or vertices?

Comment: You might interested in this question. See, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24211/graphics3d-finding-intersection-of-3d-objects-and-lines

Comment: @cormullion: Pixel!

Answer (score 6):

We can set the [`Method`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html#1591867625) option for `Graphics3D`:

```
dmap = Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1}}, .42], Cuboid[], 
  Polygon[{{-2, -2, 0}, {2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {-2, 2, 0}}], 
  Sphere[{.3, -.6, .5}, .5]}, Boxed -> False, 
  Method -> {"OneLayer" -> {"Depth", 1}}]
```

[image]

To get the distance values rescaled from 0 to 1, we can rasterize:

```
raster = ColorConvert[Rasterize[dmap], "Grayscale"];
```

We can view the depth map from different view points:

```
ListPlot3D[ImageData[raster], Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, -10}, ViewVertical -> {0, -1, 0}, Mesh -> None, 
 SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I guess this is the winning answer. Where did you find out about `Method -> {"OneLayer" -> {"Depth", 1}}` ? Also what other options are available?

Comment: ^ nevermind - found it here - a direct example: https://wolfram.com/xid/0wgrojc-tlmeyj

Comment: Right, the `Method` option has been documented in the `Graphics3D` ref page since 11.3 I believe.

Answer (score 2):

It would certainly be helpful if you could specify your input data. As an example I'll use the scene you proposed above.

Let's first extract the vertices of the 3D scene. One way to achieve this is to export the scene as an .obj and then reimport the vertex data only. Let's neglect the fact that the vertices aren't uniformly distributed over the surfaces.

```
scene = Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1}}, .42], Cuboid[], 
  Polygon[{{-2, -2, 0}, {2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {-2, 2, 0}}], Sphere[{.3, -.6, .5}, .5]}, 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {5, 5, 5}]

Export["scene.obj", scene];
impScene = Import["scene.obj", "VertexData"];
```

The camera location is at position $(5,5,5)$ as defined by `ViewPoint` above:

```
cameraLoc = {5, 5, 5};
```

These are all the lines connecting the camera to the vertices:

```
Graphics3D[Line[{cameraLoc, #}] & /@ impScene]
```

[image]

The distance from the camera to each of the vertices is easily obtained by:

```
dist = EuclideanDistance[cameraLoc, #] & /@ impScene;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need the depth of every *pixel* not only of vertices. Much like the OpenGL z-Buffer.

Answer (score 2):

One (very slow) method I've used is to sweep through the depth by increasing the `ViewRange` gradually, and rasterizing those scenes in black & white. You can then sum the resulting images to produce something that looks like a depth map.

```
drange = Range[12.0, 18, 0.05];
dimensions = {512, 512};

objects = {Cylinder[{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1}}, .42], Cuboid[], 
   Polygon[{{-2, -2, 0}, {2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {-2, 2, 0}}], 
   Sphere[{.3, -.6, .5}, .5]};

dmasks = ParallelTable[ColorNegate@ColorConvert[Rasterize[
      Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm[Black], objects}, 
       Boxed -> False, ViewRange -> {0, r}], 
      RasterSize -> dimensions], "Grayscale"], {r, drange}];

ImageAdjust@(Image[Total[ImageData /@ dmasks]])
```

[image: depth map]

This is of course inadequate for your purposes due to poor performance and low depth resolution.

Another option is to set the `VertexColors` of the mesh to a `GrayLevel` corresponding to the distance from the camera. This is faster, but it's not accurate as it interpolates the depth. Also there are some artifacts near polygon edges.

```
camera = {1.3, -2.4, 2.};
scene = Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1}}, .42], 
    Cuboid[], 
    Polygon[{{-2, -2, 0}, {2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {-2, 2, 0}}], 
    Sphere[{.3, -.6, .5}, .5]}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> camera];
(* get the whole scene as one big mesh *)
polys = TriangulateMesh[ImportString[ExportString[scene, "OBJ"]]];

coords = MeshCoordinates[polys];
cells = MeshCells[polys, 2];

(* get all polygon vertices distances to camera, normalize, and set a GrayLevel *)
distances = GrayLevel /@ Rescale[EuclideanDistance[camera, #] & /@ coords];

(* render the scene with the VertexColors *)
Rasterize[
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
    GraphicsComplex[coords, cells, VertexColors -> distances]}, 
   Boxed -> False]] // ColorNegate
```

[image: poly depth]