# Why is my GroebnerBasis = 0 in this case?

Tags: equation-solving, groebner-bases

I recently asked a question: [Finding Intersections Between Arbitrary Surface and A Line](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183959/) whose solution required me to use the `GroebnerBasis` function. I successfully applied the solution to several other cases, but am having trouble acquiring a basis for the following parametrization. Essentially, I was trying to find the intersections of an arbitrary surface with a line. The problematic surface is defined as:

```
M = 0; phi = Pi/2;
t = 1; t2 = 0.5; t3 = 0.35;

b1 = {{-Sqrt[3]/2}, {3/2}};
b2 = {{-Sqrt[3]/2}, {-3/2}};
b3 = {{Sqrt[3]}, {0}};

hx[kx_, ky_] := 
  t ((1 + Cos[{kx, ky}.b1] + Cos[{kx, ky}.b2])) + 
   t3 (2 Cos[{kx, ky}.(b1 + b2)] + Cos[{kx, ky}.(b1 - b2)]);
hy[kx_, ky_] := 
  t ((Sin[{kx, ky}.b1] - Sin[{kx, ky}.b2])) + 
   t3 Sin[{kx, ky}.(b1 - b2)];
hz[kx_, ky_] := 
 M - 2  t2 Sin[
    phi] (Sin[{kx, ky}.b1] + Sin[{kx, ky}.b2] + Sin[{kx, ky}.b3])
H[kx_, ky_] = 
  Flatten[{hx[kx, ky], hy[kx, ky], hz[kx, ky]}, 1] // Simplify;
```

I tried getting a basis using the following:

```
eqs = Thread[{x, y, 
    z} == {t ((1 + Cos[{kx, ky}.b1] + Cos[{kx, ky}.b2])) + 
     t3 (2 Cos[{kx, ky}.(b1 + b2)] + Cos[{kx, ky}.(b1 - b2)]), 
    t ((Sin[{kx, ky}.b1] - Sin[{kx, ky}.b2])) + 
     t3 Sin[{kx, ky}.(b1 - b2)], 
    M - 2  t2 Sin[
       phi] (Sin[{kx, ky}.b1] + Sin[{kx, ky}.b2] + Sin[{kx, ky}.b3])}]
impl = GroebnerBasis[Join[TrigExpand[eqs],
     {Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2 - 3 ky/2]^2 + 
        Sin[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2 - 3 ky/2]^2 == 1,
      Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2 + 3 ky/2]^2 + 
        Sin[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2 + 3 ky/2]^2 == 1,
      Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)]^2 + Sin[(Sqrt[3] kx)]^2 == 1,
      Cos[(3 ky)]^2 + Sin[(3 ky)]^2 == 1}],
    {x, y, z},
    {Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2 - 3 ky/2],
     Sin[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2 - 3 ky/2],
     Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2 + 3 ky/2],
     Sin[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2 + 3 ky/2],
     Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)],
     Sin[(Sqrt[3] kx)],
     Cos[(3 ky)],
     Sin[(3 ky)]}][[1]] // FullSimplify
```

However, I get `0` as the answer, instead of an equation of three variables.

I apologize if this question is too specific, but does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The reason for the `TrigExpand[]` is that we are helping `GroebnerBasis[]` out by making sure all cosines and sines are of the form `f[c u]` with `u` being either of `kx` or `ky`. So, you should not need to put in something like `Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2 - 3 ky/2]^2 + Sin[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2 - 3 ky/2]^2 == 1`, and the extra Pythagorean relations you need should be `Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2]^2 + Sin[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2]^2 == 1` and `Cos[ky/2]^2 + Sin[ky/2]^2 == 1`.

Comment: Also: why do you keep setting up `b1` and the other ones as $2 \times 1$ matrices? If you set them up as vectors, you wouldn't have to use `Flatten[]` at the end. Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40366)?

Comment: @J.M., thank you for the clarification! I think I figured out what's up. The result of `impl` = `-1. + Cos[0.5 ky]^2 + Sin[0.5 ky]^2` is simply 0 with `FullSimplify`. Do you have any ideas as to how I would solve for intersections in this case? (And thanks for the reference! My biggest excuse is that I started working on this with MATLAB and wasn't efficient with translating to Mathematica, but I need to change this.)

Comment: You may have to wait until I can get to a computer. But, to start you off: look carefully at the forms of the sines and cosines in the result of `TrigExpand[]`. Pair up what you can with the Pythagorean relation, and add those conditions. Then you can do your Gröbner basis.

Comment: @J.M. thanks for the suggestion. I did that before posting and I think that only those terms in your first expression matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me show another way to derive implicit Cartesian equations from a given set of parametric equations with trigonometric components. It consists of applying the Weierstrass substitution to the parameters to convert the trigonometric parametrization to a fully algebraic parametrization, which is more easily handled by `GroebnerBasis[]`. In this specific case, we tweak the substitution a bit to also get rid of the inconvenient `Sqrt[3]` factor in one of the parameters:

```
M = 0; φ = π/2;
t = 1; t2 = 1/2; t3 = 35/100;
b1 = {-Sqrt[3]/2, 3/2}; b2 = {-Sqrt[3]/2, -3/2}; b3 = {Sqrt[3], 0};

eqs = Thread[{x, y, z} ==
             TrigExpand[{t ((1 + Cos[{kx, ky}.b1] + Cos[{kx, ky}.b2])) +
                         t3 (2 Cos[{kx, ky}.(b1 + b2)] + Cos[{kx, ky}.(b1 - b2)]), 
                         t ((Sin[{kx, ky}.b1] - Sin[{kx, ky}.b2])) +
                         t3 Sin[{kx, ky}.(b1 - b2)], 
                         M - 2 t2 Sin[φ] (Sin[{kx, ky}.b1] + Sin[{kx, ky}.b2] +
                                          Sin[{kx, ky}.b3])} /.
                        {kx -> 2 ArcTan[u]/Sqrt[3], ky -> 2 ArcTan[v]}]];
```

after which, we can do

```
impl = FullSimplify[First[GroebnerBasis[eqs, {x, y, z}, {v, u}]]]
   (729 (-81 + 20 x) (1 + 20 x) + 672400 y^2)^2 ((27 - 20 x)^2 (-81 + 20 x) (-1 + 20 x) +
    800 (307 + 80 x (-17 + 5 x)) y^2 + 160000 y^4) + 16 (729 (-27 + 20 x) (1 + 20 x)
    (1053847503 + 80 x (-90404019 + 400 x (-1108566 + 740698 x + 95305 x^2))) -
    400 (176103072729 + 80 x (-145848451527 + 10 x (36677942019 + 1400 x
    (-41368297 + 2626127 x)))) y^2 - 160000 (9061532919 + 280 x (-177361853 + 80353910 x))
    y^4 - 1534040256000000 y^6) z^2 + 384160 (499023099 + 4723215840 y^2 +
    16 (x (227870091 + 10 x (-130613229 + 40 x (-271883 + 1691815 x))) +
    400 x (-1560891 + 684710 x) y^2 + 503462000 y^4)) z^4 +
    1475789056 (40 x (-2187 + 3890 x) - 3 (10323 + 38800 y^2)) z^6 + 3543369523456 z^8

ContourPlot3D[impl == 0, {x, -1, 5}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 45]
```

[image: surface]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and solution!