# Intersection between shape and line

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, intersection

I have a shape with some lines. Both are graphics in Mathematica.

```
shape =  Cuboid[{0, 0, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0}];
Graphics3D[{Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
    Line[RandomReal[1, {2, 3}]]}, {100}], {Opacity[0.2], shape}}]
```

[image]

I just want to determine, for each face of the cuboid, if a line has intersected it. I just need a true or false. I don't need the intersection coordinate, just whether the line has intersected or not. Note that some lines could intersect multiple faces.

I tried using the region tools in Mathematica, but since `Line` isn't a region, it doesn't work.

```
RegionIntersection[#, shape] & /@ 
 Table[Line[RandomReal[1, {2, 3}]], {100}]
```

I'm trying to determine if there is a pre-existing Mathematica function which can be used to quickly to find if an intersection exists for each component surface of the `Cuboid`.

---

Update:

From reading this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24211/graphics3d-finding-intersection-of-3d-objects-and-lines), This seems to work better to get the intersections with the cuboid

```
cub = Cuboid[{-2, -1, 0}, {2, 2, 2}];
lines2 = Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
    Line[RandomReal[5, {2, 3}]]}, {100}];

(intersections = {{Opacity@.8, 
       cub}, {#, 
         RegionIntersection[#2, cub] /. {_EmptyRegion -> Nothing, 
           Line -> Point}} & @@@ lines2};) // 
  AbsoluteTiming // #[[1]]/(n 5) &

Graphics3D[{Thick, lines2, AbsolutePointSize@12, intersections}, 
 ImageSize -> 800]

intersections = {{#, 
     RegionIntersection[#2, cub] /. {_EmptyRegion -> Nothing, 
       Line -> Point}} & @@@ lines2}
```

[image]

However, I'm still struggling in determining which surface the line went through...I feel there might be a solution using

```
CanonicalizePolyhedron[cub][[1]]
```

which gives the vertices of the cuboid....

Comment: Try `RegionIntersection` with `RegionBoundary[shape]`. You'll get either `EmptyRegion` or a `Point` with 0.5 in one or more coordinate place, this will indicate through what face the line went through.

Comment: It seems like a bug that `RegionIntersection` always returns an `EmptyRegion` while trying to compute an intersection in your first example though.

Comment: Your first example doesn’t work because a list is not a region. Try changing it to a RegionUnion of Line objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
lines = Line /@ RandomReal[1, {100, 2, 3}];

intersections = Function[x, 
   DeleteCases[RegionIntersection[x, #] & /@ lines, _EmptyRegion, All]];

intersectsLinesQ = intersections[#] != {} &;

faces = Polygon /@ RegionBoundary[shape][[1]]
intersectsLinesQ /@ faces
```

> {True, False, True, True, False, False}

```
facesThatIntersectLines = Select[intersectsLinesQ] @ faces;

Graphics3D[{Opacity[.1], faces, 
 {Opacity[.5], RandomColor[], #, Opacity[1], PointSize[Large],
      intersections @ #} & /@ facesThatIntersectLines, 
  Opacity[1], {RandomColor[], #} & /@ lines}]
```

[image]